# Using functiontools partial with qpushbutton

Tags: python

I'm trying to use partial with a qpushbutton to call a method in another file but I get AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'number'

file1.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
from functools import partial

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton

import file2

class window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 220)
        button = QPushButton(self)
        button.setText('Open')
        button.clicked.connect(partial(file2.open.get, self))
        self.number = 10
        self.show()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = window()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

file2.py

```
class open:
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

  def get(self, parent):
    print(parent.number)
```

Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/john/github/pyqt5/QFileDialog/file2.py", line 9, in get
    print(parent.number)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'number'
Aborted
```

If I change file1.py to:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
from functools import partial

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton

import file2

class window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 220)
        button = QPushButton(self)
        button.setText('Open')
        openclass = file2.open()
        button.clicked.connect(partial(openclass.get, self))
        self.number = 10
        self.show()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = window()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

and add a with open I get TypeError: open.**init**() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

file2.py

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog

class open:
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def get(self, parent):
        print(parent.number)

        fileName = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(parent, "Select a File")

        print(fileName[0])

        with open(fileName[0]) as f:
            line = f.readline()
            print(line)
```

Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/john/github/pyqt5/QFileDialog/file2.py", line 15, in get
    with open(fileName[0]) as f:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: open.__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
Aborted
```

Thanks for looking
JT

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text (formatted as code) in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The answer for problem 2 is don't name your class the same as a built in function...

Corrected code:
File1.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
from functools import partial

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton

import file2

class window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 220)
        button = QPushButton(self)
        button.setText('Open')
        openclass = file2.openit()
        button.clicked.connect(partial(openclass.get, self))
        self.number = 10
        self.show()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = window()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

file2.py

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog

class openit:
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def get(self, parent):
        print(parent.number)

        fileName = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(parent, "Select a File")

        print(fileName[0])

        with open(fileName[0]) as f:
            line = f.readline()
            print(line)
```

JT